# c++ string::find_last_of returns arbitrary large number

Tags: c++, string

Trying to get the index of the last '=' in a string with find last returns a garbage number.

```
size_t index = str.find_last_of('=', 0);
```

Here is the string, there is definently an '=' in it..

```
"page id=0 file="simsun.png" chars count=97"
```

How do i find the index of the last '=' ?

Answer (score 6):

In terms of `string::find_last_of()`, specifying `pos` means that the search only includes characters *at or before* that position, ignoring any possible occurrences after it. If it cannot be found given those limitations, `npos` is returned.

Full details can be found in the standard, for example `C++11 21.4.7.5`:

---

> **21.4.7.5 `basic_string::find_last_of` [string::find.last.of]**
>
> `size_type find_last_of(`
>      `const basic_string& str,`
>      `size_type pos = npos`
> `) const noexcept;`
>
> *Effects:* Determines the highest position `xpos`, if possible, such that both of the following conditions obtain:
>
> - `xpos <= pos` and `xpos < size()`;
> - `traits::eq(at(xpos), str.at(I))` for some element `I` of the string controlled by `str`.
>
> *Returns:* `xpos` if the function can determine such a value for `xpos`. Otherwise, returns `npos`.
>
> *Remarks:* Uses `traits::eq()`.
>
> ---
>
> `size_type find_last_of(`
>      `charT c,`
>      `size_type pos = npos`
> `) const noexcept;`
>
> *Returns:* `find_last_of(basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>(1,c),pos)`.

---

It's that `xpos <= pos` in the first bullet point that's causing the problem here. Unless your string actually *starts* with `=`, your particular expression is going to get `npos` as a result. *That's* the large number you're seeing as it's an unsigned variant of the value `-1`.

The correct form of `find_last_of()` if you want to find the last character is:

```
size_t index = str.find_last_of('=');
```

Since `pos` defaults to `npos`, meaning that it considers the *entire* string.

Comment: And for people like me who only skimmed the documentation, note he said **characters** not strings. If you're looking for the last instance of a whole string, use `rfind`.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it's "arbitrary", rather it's most likely `npos` that is returned.

And it's easy to see why if you read e.g. [this `find_last_of` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of), where it says that the `pos` argument is

> position at which the search is to finish

So when you pass `0` as the position, you tell `find_last_of` to stop searching at the first character instead of the last.

The simple solution is to not pass the (optional) position argument at all:

```
str.find_last_of('=')
```

And of course to have a check for `npos` being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Second argument is wrong, try:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    std::string str = "page id = 0 file = \"simsun.png\" chars count = 97";
    size_t index = str.find_last_of('=');
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **rfind()** for the last occurrence and **find_last_of()** to find the character in string from the end

***To be specific you are asking for the last occurrence so use rfind() instead of find_last_of()***

```
std::string str ("page id=0 file=\"simsun.png\" chars count=97");
std::string key ("=");
std::size_t found = str.rfind(key);
```

Comment: Why the distinction? The functions can indeed have different purposes but, when you're searching for a *single* character (as in this question), there's no difference.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes it's true for single character